# Can you help me identify this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I'm planning to buy this bike that the owner claims is a bike from 1940's with all original parts except the seat. I'm going to purchase this for $70 CDN, if you guys could help me identify the bike and/or tell me whether this is a good price, it would be of great help

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your link to the picture is not working. It would be best anyway if you included the photos directly in the post, plus perhaps a link to the listing.

Comment: Not a good enough picture to tell much.  It is believable that it's from the 40s.  Not a good bike to ride very much, but if you're into antiques it's probably worth $70 for it's curiosity value, assuming it doesn't look too bad up close.

Comment: That's a very cool old bike. Looks like it would be quite a project to restore, but it could be fun. I'm not so sure about the brakes – looks like front wheel only and probably not too effective. But, if you're not fanatical about keeping the bike original perhaps you could install a rear hub with a coaster brake – seems like that would look pretty close to original, but would give you more braking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the 1950s, this type of braking system was becoming obsolete, so it's no later than that.

I found a few pictures on the net that look like your bike. They're all British, and all from the 1930s: [Mercury](https://oldbike.wordpress.com/1939-ladies-loopframe-the-mercury-cycle/), [BSA](http://www.sterba-bike.cz/produkt/bsa-ladies-1936?lang=EN), [Raleigh](http://www.flickriver.com/groups/1385513@N22/pool/random/). In those days, the British companies all basically made the same bikes, so it's hard to tell them apart. Look more closely at the front of the head tube - there might be a badge there.

Is it a good price? You'll probably spend way more than $70 to restore it, so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Arya It is kind to both accept the answer (which it appears that you did) and to upvote it as well. That helps to build the answer's reputation and rewards her/him/they for the work that went into researching and writing up the answer.